# Type 'Array<any>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'. Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'Array<any>'

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am getting error at the line `let result: Array<any> = a.Where(func);`. Method `where` returns `Array<any>` though I am getting error.

```
    export {};

    type Predicate<T> = (item: T) => boolean;

    interface KeyArrayPair<K, T> {
        Key: K;
        Value: Array<T>;
    }

    declare global {
        interface Array<T> {
            First: {
                (): T;
                (Func: Predicate<T>): T;
            };
            Where(Func: Predicate<T>): Array<T>;
        }
    }

    Array.prototype.Where = function (func: (x: any) => boolean): Array<any> {
        let result: Array<any> = [];
        let a: Array<any> = this;
        for (let i of a) {
            if (func(i)) {
                result.push(i);
            }
        }
        return result;
    };

    Array.prototype.First = function (func?: (x: any) => boolean): any {
        let a: Array<any> = this;
        if (a.length === 0) {
            throw 'Array does not contain elements';
        }
        if (!func) {
            return a[0];
        }
        let result: Array<any> = a.Where(func);
        if (result.length === 0) {
            throw 'Array does not contain elements';
        }
        return result[0];
    };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following works just fine in a new `foo.ts` file:

```
interface Array<T> {
    first: {
        (): T;
        (Func: (x: T) => boolean): T;
    };
    where(Func: (x: T) => boolean): Array<T>;
}
Array.prototype.where = function(func: (x: any) => boolean): Array<any> {
    let result: Array<any> = [];
    let a: Array<any> = this;
    for (let i of a) {
        if (func(i)) {
            result.push(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
};

Array.prototype.first = function(func?: (x: any) => boolean): any {
    let a: Array<any> = this;
    if (a.length === 0) {
        throw 'Array does not contain elements';
    }
    if (!func) {
        return a[0];
    }
    let result: Array<any> = a.where(func);
    if (result.length === 0) {
        throw 'Array does not contain elements';
    }
    return result[0];
};
```

## More

Perhaps you are doing this in a module. Please do in a *global* file : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html

Comment: could you explain what is`global` file. Actually I wrote the code as follows...
       `export {};
       declare global {
          interface Array<T> {
               first: {
                     (): T;
                     (Func: (x: T) => boolean): T;
                };
                where(Func: (x: T) => boolean): Array<T>;
              }
        }`

Comment: global vs. modules : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: Please copy and past into the `typescript play ground`. There also i am getting the same error.  [Typescript Play Ground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

For time being I am using casting object as follows. Is it okay?
`let result: Array<any> = <[]>a.where(func);`

Comment: This is bug in typescript. [Issue #8327](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8327#issuecomment-214986392).
They fixed and Available in master branch.  
Thank for your support.